# Analog of p-height in Abelian groups for Modules over Dedekind Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, dedekind-domain, torsion-groups

For purposes of this post, I'll confine myself to talking about torsion Abelian groups and torsion modules over a Dedekind domain.

If $A$ is an Abelian $p$-group, then heights of elements play an important role in studying the group. So the $p$-height of an element is finite, or $h_p (a) = n$, if $p^n x = a$ has a solution $x \in A$. Equivalently $a \in p^n A$ but not $p^{n+1}A$.

The **first Ulm subgroup** of $A$ contains the elements of infinite height $A^1 = \{ a \in A \mid h_p (a) = \infty \} = \{ a \in A \mid a \in \bigcap_{n \geq 0 } p^n A \} $.

Now every Abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, and every PID is a Dedekind domain. Unless I'm mistaken, we can define **$p$-height** and the **first Ulm submodule** in an identical manner for a PID. Our prime $p$ comes from a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p} = \langle p \rangle$.

--------------------At last, here is my set-up and question--------------------

If $A_R$ is a torsion module over a Dedekind domain $R$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then can we say that $a \in A$ has finite $\mathfrak{p}$-height $n$ if and only if $a \in \mathfrak{p}^{n}A$ but not $\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}A$?

Furthermore, for a torsion module $A$ where $\forall a \in A$, $\mathfrak{p}^n a = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is the first Ulm submodule $A^1$ defined to be $\bigcap_{n \geq 0} \mathfrak{p}^n A$ ?

*Any explanation or references would be quite helpful* as I have combed through Fuch's *Modules over non-Noetherian Domains* and *Modules over Valuation Domains* as well as Kaplansky's paper [Modules over Dedekind Rings and Valuation Rings](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwxv-f2ozVAhVq5IMKHQi1DSIQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Ftran%2F1952-072-02%2FS0002-9947-1952-0046349-0%2FS0002-9947-1952-0046349-0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF3E-GTpoOzZWqUwD2QuW9k_49mow) for some time now. I found the introduction of [Tilting Modules over Small Dedekind Domains](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404901001311) by Trlifaj & Wallutis to be helpful but there is no mention of $\mathfrak{p}$-height in it.